# How do you do Dependency Injection In a class that inherits DialogContainer? BotFramework v4

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, botframework

I've been searching for a day and a half now and still can't find a solution.

For a bot I'm making it is necessary to do a few api calls with the received data from the client. However I can't figure out how to dependency injection in a constructor that inherits from DialogContainer.

I've tried to use property injection and constructor injection from autofac. I tried to add a second constructor who does the DI but the result was that the needed surface were null. And the same for the property injection, the services always return null.

When using a dialog in BotFramework v4, I've noticed you have to do the conversation in the constructor. I assume the reason why it won't work is because all the bot logic is in a constructor so autofac isn't able to properly wire up the services.

Answer (score 2):

This is an active topic for botframework-v4 on GitHub right now. Here is a [good link to the GH repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/876#issuecomment-415888314) summarizing the situation. There is an excellent comment written by drub0y.

Essentially, middleware is only run once when initializing the constructor, and there isn't currently a way to inject scoped dependencies.

Since this is still an active topic, I'm optimistic that there will be new information available on scoped dependency injection in the near future.

Comment: Hey @JoeB, there is still some active discussion about DI in BotBuilder-dotnet v4: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/357 https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/860 and https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1188